# Bootstrap modal window not appearing

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I took the code for the bootstrap modal window directly from the bootstrap site, so I have this in my .html.erb file. But nothing appears on the page when I click the button. Anybody have any thoughts on why this might be?

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you add everything is needed? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Greg! So there are a few possibilities here. One thing I'd recommend is checking to see if the modal is on the page using dev tools and trying to add a z-index style of 9999 to it. This would force it to the front of everything. If the modal appears than you probably have a layering issue.

Comment: I have added everything and I know i have because I have other bootstrap features that work fine. I changed the z-index from 1050 to 9999 though and still haven't had it appear

Comment: when I look in dev tools the styling for the modal is clearly all crossed out, how do I figure out where the styling is being overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to check if your project is using BS jQuery modal plugin. As in the docs:

> Modals are built with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Are you sure you have JS code linked to the button? Basically something like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#via-javascript. How do you installed BS in your project?